# Knockout/Jqm radio button not being checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have this code to display two radio buttons, for the user to choose Yes or No.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Choose</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="pref" id="radio1" value="yes" data-bind="checked: $root.selected" />
       <label for="radio1">YES</label>
    <input type="radio" name="pref" id="radio2" value="no" data-bind="checked: $root.selected" />
       <label for="radio2">NO</label>
</fieldset>
```

When the page is displayed, irrespective of the value of $root.selected (yes/no), neither radio button is checked. After much debugging, I found it works if I remove the label element, or even if I change label tag to span/div tag.

Any idea why no radio button is checked with label?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just at '  checked /> ' at the end of one of them, the appropriate button is checked.

Answer (score 0):

jQM hides native radio/checkbox and wrap them in `label`. The `label` receives all styles to look as *checked*. When you change `.prop()` of a radio/checkbox to either `true` or `false`, you need to *re-enhance* / *refresh* the element manually, `$(element).checkboxradio("refresh")`.

I'm not a [knockout.js](/questions/tagged/knockout.js) expert, but below is an example to achieve what you want.

```js
var viewModel = function (status, elm) {
    var self = this;
    self.bar = ko.observable(status ? status.bar : false);
    /* refresh radio/checkbox to re-apply styles */
    self.foo = $(elm).prop("checked", self.bar()).checkboxradio("refresh");
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel({
    bar: true
}, $("#radio1")));
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KCrtP/)**